# Is there another way to think of/draw this simple diagram?

Tags: diodes, circuit-analysis

I'm not too familiar with this "not-fully-connected" type of diagram, and so understanding it is giving me some trouble. How do I approach determining the following circuit's characteristics (i.e. currents, voltage drops, etc.)?

My mind wants to just connect the grounded parts, trace them back to the back of **V1** (Thereby assuming **V1** is a battery, and treating **V2** as a measure of the voltage across the resistor on the right and/or the diode. However, I'm not sure if it's that simple.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG32S7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It *is* that simple.

Comment: As Dwayne stated, it really is that simple. Such a diagram should be accompanied with a description of each label or an appropriate legend to indicate intent. For instance, V2 could be the battery and V1 a measure point. However, it is convention to "read" from left to right and my immediate assumption of this circuit would be as your describe with V1 being the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here :) don't be afraid to change it up. You are not wrong by imagining those two grounds connected. If it works for you, then go with it.

[image]

Sorry for the poorly drawn image hahahaha